# How to place an Image between 2 text string in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I need to place an Image between 2 text strings. Pl see the code below. As I have tried but the first text overlapping the image. Pl help me to fix the issue.

**Code**

```
 // Create a new Phrase and add the image to it
                    var cellContent = new Phrase();

                    var fontHeader = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", BaseFont.CP1250, true, 12, 0);
                    cellContent.Add(new Paragraph("\n" + "Default Header", fontHeader));

                    Code39BarcodeDraw barcode39 = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code39WithoutChecksum;
                    System.Drawing.Image img = barcode39.Draw(val[cnt], 25);
                    var pdfImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ReadImage(img));
                    var width = pdfImg.PlainWidth;
                    if (width > colWidths.ToArray()[0])
                        pdfImg.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(width - 20);
                    cellContent.Add(new Chunk(pdfImg, 0, 0));

                    var font = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", BaseFont.CP1250, true, 12, 0);
                    cellContent.Add(new Chunk("\n" + val[cnt], font));
                    cnt += 1;

                    //Create a new cell specifying the content
                    var cell = new PdfPCell(cellContent);

                    //Ensure our label height is adhered to
                    cell.FixedHeight = _label.Height;

                    //Centre align the content
                    cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                    cell.Border = IncludeLabelBorders ? Rectangle.BOX : Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

                    //Add to the row
                    rowCells.Add(cell);
```

Comment: Do you want the image to be between text *horizontally* or *vertically*? That's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
cellContent.Add(new Chunk(pdfImg, 0, 0));
```

To:

```
cellContent.Add(new Chunk(pdfImg, 0, 0, true));
```

This way, the *leading* of the `Phrase` will adapt to the height of the `Image`.

Comment: yup. works so great but the text getting broken to next lines. ie, Word `Default` in first line and `Header` in the next line even though there are enough spaces to accommodate full string.

Comment: What if you add a `" "` after `Header` like this: `"Default Header "`

Comment: It should not break the word if there are enough spaces to present it on the single line. No matter if it breaks the word because of no space.

Comment: There is not enough space for the "word + the image", hence it breaks before the "word + the image". Isn't that logical?

Comment: OK. I got it what is wrong. thanks for the nice explanation. I solved it by using line break.